# Jackrabbit 2.6.0 compatibility with Java 6

Tags: java, jackrabbit

We've recently upgraded from Jackrabbit 2.4.0 to Jackrabbit 2.6.0. Jackrabbit is deployed into JBoss AS 7.1.0. We still use Java 6. 
  From Jackrabbit 2.6.0 manifest file we see that is build using Java 7.
  Is there anything to worry about using Jackrabbit 2.6.0 with Java 6 (actually are there any specific features used from Java 7 by Jackrabbit 2.6.0 codebase)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jackrabbit parent POM](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jackrabbit/branches/2.6/jackrabbit-parent/pom.xml) of the 2.6 version clearly indicates using Java 6 for compilation.

Relevant sections pasted below

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <target>1.6</target>
      <source>1.6</source>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <!-- Generate aggregate Javadocs -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <aggregate>true</aggregate>
      <links>
        <link>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/</link>
        <link>http://www.day.com/maven/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/</link>
      </links>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <!-- JCR-988: IDE plugins -->
  <plugin>
    <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/ -->
    <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
      <jdkLevel>1.6</jdkLevel>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```